# Can someone help me in understanding the SCTP stats captured on linux

Tags: linux, telecommunication, sctp, lte, ss7

I am new to SCTP protocol and trying to figure out how to interpret the SCTP stats captured by /proc/net/sctp

```
The output shows something like this.
2016-04-26 07:21:17
ASSOC     SOCK   STY SST ST HBKT ASSOC-ID TX_QUEUE RX_QUEUE UID INODE LPORT RPORT LADDRS <-> RADDRS HBINT INS OUTS MAXRT T1X T2X RTXC wmema wmemq sndbuf rcvbuf
ce0f1800 cd7ede00 2   1   3  11661 1783      423        0      77 292723 36422 36423  10.205.8.71 <-> *10.205.8.72                  3000    10    10   10    0    0        0      873      704   163840   163840
ca625800 cd7ec000 2   1   3  65210    1        0        0      77 10344 3223  36412  10.205.8.71 <-> *10.205.0.135           3000     2     2   10    0    0        3        1        0   163840   163840
ENDPT     SOCK   STY SST HBKT LPORT   UID INODE LADDRS
ca511d80 cd7ec3c0 2   10  40   36422    77 10345 10.205.8.71 
ADDR ASSOC_ID HB_ACT RTO MAX_PATH_RTX REM_ADDR_RTX  START
10.205.8.72  1783 1 200 5 0 0
10.205.0.135  1 1 200 15 0 0
SctpCurrEstab                   2
SctpActiveEstabs                              21
SctpPassiveEstabs                           1855
SctpAborteds                    272
SctpShutdowns                                1808
SctpOutOfBlues                                0
SctpChecksumErrors                      0
SctpOutCtrlChunks                          79214
SctpOutOrderChunks                     327396
SctpOutUnorderChunks               0
SctpInCtrlChunks                             268038
SctpInOrderChunks                        174268
SctpInUnorderChunks                   0
SctpFragUsrMsgs                             0
SctpReasmUsrMsgs                        0
SctpOutSCTPPacks                          406626
SctpInSCTPPacks                              385959
SctpT1InitExpireds                           0
SctpT1CookieExpireds                   0
SctpT2ShutdownExpireds            0
SctpT3RtxExpireds                           5
SctpT4RtoExpireds                          0
SctpT5ShutdownGuardExpireds                0
SctpDelaySackExpireds                  9869
SctpAutocloseExpireds                  0
SctpT3Retransmits                          5
SctpPmtudRetransmits                 0
SctpFastRetransmits                       14
SctpInPktSoftirq                               384346
SctpInPktBacklog                             1613
SctpInPktDiscards                            0
SctpInDataChunkDiscards            0
```

Can some one help me understand this or provide the link where i can get some information.

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 1):

The linux man page for SCTP (http://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp) has most of them covered - for example:

> **SctpChecksumErrors**
>   The number of SCTP packets received with an invalid checksum.
>
> **SctpOutCtrlChunks**
>          The number of SCTP control chunks sent (retransmissions are not included). Control chunks are those chunks different from DATA.
>
> **SctpOutOrderChunks**
>   The number of SCTP ordered data chunks sent (retransmissions are not included).
>   SctpOutUnorderChunks

If there is a particular one you were wondering about, maybe let us know?